# pass information between windows in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have one window of Qt that shows the clients name in a QListWidget. When I double-click on it, a new window come up and has to show the line edit with the name on it and a button for saving changes.

I made the new window and the line edit in that window but I do not know how to pass de QString "name" into that window from the main window

Answer (score 1):

Just call [setText()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#text-prop) on the new window's line edit after you create the window. I assume you are using the [QListWidget::itemDoubleClicked()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#itemDoubleClicked) signal to detect the double click. That signal passes a [QListWidgetItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidgetitem.html) pointer as parameter. So if you connected that signal to a slot that takes a `QListWidgetItem*` parameter, then you get the text of the double-clicked entry through the [QListWidgetItem::text()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidgetitem.html#text) function:

```
void mySlot(QListWidgetItem* item)
{
    // Create the new window and the line edit.
    // ...

    lineEdit->setText(item->text());

    // Now show the new window.
}
```